# Let $x_1 = 2 $, and define $x_{n+1} = \frac{1} {2} (x_n + \frac {2} {x_n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that $x^2_n $ is always greater than or equal to $2$. And then use this to prove that $$x_n - x_{n+1} \geqslant 0 \quad \text{for any } n \in \mathbb{N}$$ Hence conclude that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sqrt{2}$.

$\bullet~$ I can show that $x^2_n \geqslant 2$ by induction:

- Basis step: $x_1=2, x_1^2 = 4 >2$.
- Inductive step:
  Assume we have some $k$ for which $x^2_K \geqslant 2$, then

\begin{align*}
(x_{k+1})^2 =&~ \bigg(\dfrac{1} {2} \bigg(x_k + \dfrac{2} {x_k}\bigg)\bigg)^2\\
=&~ \dfrac{1} {4} x_k^2 + 1 + \dfrac{1} {x_k^2}\\
\geqslant&~ \dfrac {1} {4} x_k^2 + 1 \geqslant 2\\
&~\dfrac {1} {4} x_k^2 \geqslant 1  \quad \forall~ n \geqslant 2
\end{align*}

How do I use this to show that $$x_n - x_{n+1} \geqslant 0 \quad \text{for any } n \in \mathbb{N}$$
and hence conclude that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sqrt{2}$?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the fact that $x_{n+1} =\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{2}{x_{n}}) \le \frac{1}{2}(x_n+x_{n})=x_{n}$ from $x_{n}^2 \ge 2$ (or $x_{n} \ge \frac{2}{x_{n}}$)

Thus, $x_{n}-x_{n+1}\le0$.

This implies that $x_{n}$ is a decreasing sequence that is greater than $\sqrt{2}$, implying that $x_{n}$ is convergent.

Let $\lim{x_n}=a$.

Note the fact that $a=\frac{1}{2}(a+\frac{2}{a})$. This implies that $a=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: could you help me modify the sequence so that it converges to $\sqrt{a}$? I thought I had it with $a=\dfrac{1} {c} (a + \dfrac{c} {a})$ but it doesn't seem to work that way. Thanks!

Comment: If your trying to make it converge to $\sqrt{a}$, why don't you just try $\sqrt{x_{n}}$? But I don't think I perfectly understand you, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Part b wants the original sequence modified so that it converges to $ \sqrt{a} $ instead of $\sqrt{2}$. I am still having a bit of trouble with that. Thanks!

Comment: $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+\frac{c}{x_{n}})$ would work.

Comment: If $x_n^2 \ge 2$, is it fine to write $x_n \ge \frac{2}{x_n}$, without any knowledge of the sign of $x_n$?

Comment: @Quasar In this case positivity can pretty easily be seen through induction, so yeah.

Answer (score 3):

$$x_n-x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac12\left(x_n+\frac 2{x_n}\right)=\frac{2x_n^2-x_n^2-2}{2x_n}=\frac{x_n^2-2}{2x_n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

By $AM\geq GM$, 
$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} \left( x_{n}+\frac{2}{x_{n}} \right)
\geq \sqrt{2}$ and $x_{1}=2$, therefore
$$x_{n}^{2} \geq 2 \: , \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Now,
\begin{align*}
  x_{n}-x_{n+1} &=\frac{x_{n}^{2}-2}{x_{n}} \\
                &\geq 0
\end{align*}
So $\{ x_{n} \}$ is decreasing and

\begin{align*}
  x_{n}-x_{n+1} &\leq \frac{x_{1}^{2}-2}{2^{n/2}} \\
                &= \frac{2}{2^{n/2}}
\end{align*}

Hence $\lim_{n\to \infty} (x_{n}-x_{n+1})=0$ and $\{ x_{n} \}$ is decreasing but bounded below, 
$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n}$ exists.

Therefore $L=\frac{1}{2} \left( L+\frac{2}{L} \right) \implies L=\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Given that our defined sequence $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below by $\sqrt2$, we can use a proof by contradiction to show that it converges to $\sqrt2$.

The sequence $x_n$ must converge but assume that

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lambda \sqrt{2}$$

with fixed $\lambda \gt 1$.

Now since for arbitrary $\varepsilon \gt 0$ we can write

$$\lambda \sqrt2 - .5\,\big(\lambda \sqrt2  + \varepsilon +\frac{2}{\lambda \sqrt2  + \varepsilon}\big) = \frac{\lambda^2 - 0.5 \varepsilon^2 - 1}{\lambda \sqrt2 + \varepsilon}$$

and we can find small enough $\varepsilon$ satisfying

$$ \lambda^2 - 0.5 \varepsilon^2 - 1 \gt 0$$

there would have to exist $x_n$ satisfying

$$ x_n \lt \lambda \sqrt{2}$$

giving us a contradiction.