# $x_1 = 2 $, and define $x_{n+1} = \frac{1} {2} (x_n + \frac {2} {x_n})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that $x^2_n $ is always greater than or equal to $2$. And then use this to prove that $$x_n - x_{n+1} \geqslant 0 \quad \text{for any } n \in \mathbb{N}$$ Hence conclude that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sqrt{2}$.

I've read this post [Let $x_1 = 2 $, and define $x_{n+1} = \frac{1} {2} (x_n + \frac {2} {x_n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665029/1214926), but it doesn't prove that $x_{n+1} >2$ in the inductive step since $\dfrac {1} {4} x_k^2 + 1 \geqslant 2$ is not necessary true because we can only affirm $\dfrac {1} {4} x_k^2 + 1 \geqslant \dfrac{1}{2} + 1$.

How do I prove $(x_n)^2 \geqslant 2 \quad \forall~ n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It is not supposed to show $x_{n+1}>2,$ it is supposed to show $x_{n+1}^2>2.$

Comment: Hint: AM/GM means $\frac12(x+2/x)>\sqrt 2.$

Comment: Use convexity of $x \mapsto x^2-2$.

Comment: Do you want the closed form formula of $x_n$? This formula exists. And from it, we can deduce directly the result

Answer (score 2):

We can write

$$ [\,.5 (x + \frac{2}{x})\,]^2 = .25 x^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2} $$

and

$$ .25 x^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{x^2}  \ge 2 \text{ iff } x^4  + 4x^2  +4 \ge 8x^2 \text{ iff } x^4 - 4x^2 + 4 \ge 0  $$

and

$$ x^4 - 4x^2 + 4 = (x^2 - 2)^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = {1 \over 2} (x + {2 \over x})$. Show that the minimum of $g$ for $x>0$ occurs at $x^*=\sqrt{2}$ and $g(x^*) = \sqrt{2}$. Hence $x_n \ge \sqrt{2}$.
Since $x_{n+1} - x_n = - {x^2 -2 \over 2 x_n}$ we see that $x_{n+1} \le x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $x_n^2 > 2$ proving that $x_{n+1}^2 > 1 + \frac{1}{4}x_n^2$, then using induction.

I.e.: $x_{n+1}^2 = \frac{1}{4} x_n^2 + 1  + \frac{1}{x_n^2} > \frac{1}{4}x_n^2 + 1$